# Insert multiple values for single foreign key field from one table into another table

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

here i hav 2 tables

```
tbl_slaUpdate
tbl_eslaUser
```

IN tbl_slaUpdate has

SlaId as uniqueidenfier as primarykey

and it already have some values

IN tbl_eslaUser has

```
userid as uniqueidentifier as primarykey
and username and
slaId as Foreign key as uniqueidentifier
```

here i have to insert multiple UserId and username into single slaid
actualy im getting the username from listbox
where the gridview is selected by checkbox

like tbl_eslauser

```
userid UserName SlaId
1322    robert      1234
1435    jhon        1234
1578    albert      1234

1345    albert     2345
1678    jhon1      2345
1456    robert     2345

1389    robert2    3456
1267    jhon       3456
1568    albert     3456
```

Comment: welcome to StackOverflow. Please state more clearly what exactly you want to achieve. Also keep in mind that you usually propose somemething you already have (do you have some Insert query that does not do what you want) rather than asking for ready solution. You can read [this](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) about how to write question when asking something that does not work. And also you can read something about what is [on-topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) here.

Comment: What is the problem? Can you provide where in the code you think you may have a problem or can you clearly explain what it is you are trying to achieve

Comment: Actually here i have the two tables tbl_sla i have to insert one primary key S_ID values into another table tbl_user and but for that each value of S_ID has  multiple U_ID and U_Name . @Eminem

Answer (score 0):

userid, username and slaId are your real composite Primary Key for tbl_eslaUser. If you don't want to use a composite key, then you would have to add another column of auto increment, and use it as tbl_eslaUser's PK.  Either way you would have to change the PK.